# How to send data to apple tv app from my iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-tv

I'd like to know if there is a way to send some data from my iphone to my apple tv.I'll explain:I want to make an app for my apple tv and extend this app to my iphone.Using the extension in running on the iphone you should send some data to my app in running on my apple tv.Sending data it should not be through wi-fi but using for example the bluethoot.How should I do to build this comunication?Can you explain to me how to do or link me some resources?Thanks to all!

Ps. sorry for my english!

Comment: This library might help what you need. https://github.com/rsattar/Voucher

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MultipeerConnectivity framework should allow you to do this. It's available in the SDK and supported by both tvOS and iOS.

The advantage is that you don't have to chose what type of connection the devices use. It supports both WiFi and BT. But if you don't want to use WiFi because wifi is not available, it can by default create a peer to peer wifi network between devices.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/multipeerconnectivity

And also, here https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-create-a-peer-to-peer-network-using-the-multipeer-connectivity-framework is a good tutorial.